# I got a RunTime error SIGCONT for the below code

Tags: c++, c++11, runtime-error, out-of-memory

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n,ctr=0;
        cin>>n;
        int a[n],ptr=750;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>a[i];
            if(a[i]<ptr){
                ctr++;
                ptr=a[i];
            }
        }
        cout<<ctr-(n/5)+1<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**All other answers say I would have divided by zero or accessed out of bounds but here I do not find any such situation**

Comment: `int a[n]` - VLA is not legal in C++ and may silently fail

Comment: Try with `int a[1000]` instead of `int a[n]` and report back. Also [edit] your question and show a minimal input that triggers the problem.

Comment: This sounds strange. `SIGCONT` is sent *to*  a process after it has been stopped in order for the OS to start it again. It is not triggered by the process itself, and is not usually considered a runtime error.